# VSCode SSH Remote connected to EC2 instance, "shell integration failed to activate" for zsh based terminal

Tags: shell, visual-studio-code, amazon-ec2, ssh, arm64

### VSCode SSH Remote connected to AWS EC2 instance running Ubuntu 20.04 (ARM64)

I'm connecting to the instance using AWS SSM through the Remote SSH extension (see more detail about how here: https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-vscode/issues/941) which is working fine, but zsh shell integration fails with the message `Shell integration failed to activate`:

[image: Launching a shell integrated zsh terminal]

[image: Resulting in the shell integration failed to activate error]

Meanwhile, I can easily create a bash based terminal and write `$ zsh` afterwards:

[image: Launching a shell integrated bash termnial]

[image: Resulting in working terminal]

[image: And manually entering zsh works as well]

The is the output generated in the `Log (Window)` Output pane of VSCode:

```
[2022-08-09 19:22:35.667] [renderer1] [error] EPERM: operation not permitted, copyfile 
'/data/home/pens/.vscode-server/bin/da76f93349a72022ca4670c1b84860304616aaa2/out/vs/workbench/contrib/terminal/browser/media/shellIntegration-rc.zsh'
-> '/tmp/vscode-zsh/.zshrc':
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, copyfile
'/data/home/pens/.vscode-server/bin/da76f93349a72022ca4670c1b84860304616aaa2/out/vs/workbench/contrib/terminal/browser/media/shellIntegration-rc.zsh'
-> '/tmp/vscode-zsh/.zshrc'
```

It prints a similar error for the following dot-files files: `.zcompdump, .zlogin, .zprofile, .zshenv, .zshrc`

---

**Ultimately this means that the issue is related to access to the files in the directory: `/tmp/vscode-zsh/`**

VSCode tries to create the 5 dot-files in the same folder with the same naming for the current user whenever it tries to launch a shell integrated zsh terminal. This results in `permission denied / operation not permitted` if the files have already been created for - and are owned by - another user.. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I experience the same issue after upgrading VS Code to the latest version today.

Comment: Filed a bug with VS Code here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/157855

Comment: Good to know others are having the same issue with the recent upgrade.

Comment: Same issue on my local dev machine with multiple vscode users. I "fixed" it by disabling terminal integration in settings.json via `"terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.enabled": false`

Comment: More information and other workarounds here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/157611

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was caused by the 1.70 update of VSCode, an issue has been raised on the VSCode github: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/157611

In the meantime the fix is to disable shellIntegration in your VSCode settings: `"terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.enabled": false` and add the following to your `.zshrc`:

```
[[ "$TERM_PROGRAM" == "vscode" ]] && . "$(code --locate-shell-integration-path zsh)"
```